# Unable to change value of dataframe at specific location

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to go through my dataframe in pandas and if the value of two columns is equal to something, then I change a value in that location, here is a simplified version of the loop I've been using (I changed the values of the if/else function because the original used regex and stuff and was quite complicated):

```
pro_cr = ["IgA", "IgG", "IgE"] # CR's considered productive
rows_changed = 0
prod_to_unk = 0
unk_to_prod = 0

changed_ids = []

for index in df_sample.index:
    if num=1 and color="red":
        pass
    elif num=2 and color="blue":
        prod_to_unk += 1
        changed_ids.append(df_sample.loc[index, "Sequence ID"])
        df_sample.at[index, "Functionality"] = "unknown"
        rows_changed += 1
    elif num=3 and color="green":
        unk_to_prod += 1
        changed_ids.append(df_sample.loc[index, "Sequence ID"])
        df_sample.at[index, "Functionality"] = "productive"
        rows_changed += 1
    else:
        pass

print("Number of productive columns changed to unknown: {}".format(prod_to_unk))
print("Number of unknown columns changed to productive: {}".format(unk_to_prod))
print("Total number of rows changed: {}".format(rows_changed))
```

So the main problem is the changing code:

`df_sample.at[index, "Functionality"] = "unknown" # or productive`

If I run this code without these lines of code, it works properly, it finds all the correct locations, tells me how many were changed and what their ID's are, which I can use to validate with the CSV file.

If I use `df_sample["Functionality"][index] = "unknown" # or productive` the code runs, but checking the rows that have been changed shows that they were not changed at all.

When I use `df.at[row, column] = value` I get "AttributeError: 'BlockManager' object has no attribute 'T'"

I have no idea why this is showing up. There are no duplicate columns. Hope this was clear (if not let me know and I'll try to clarify it). Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `df_sample.loc[index, "Functionality"] = "unknown"`?

Comment: lol yes that worked, thanks so much, any ideas why that worked but df.at did not?

Comment: Is there no way around using a loop in your code?

Comment: I can't think of a better way, my if statements rely on regex and other conditions in up to 3 different columns and I'm not sure if I can do it a different way. I'd love to if there was a better, more performant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I've never used `df.at` - but try using `df.loc` instead:

```
df_sample.loc[index, "Functionality"] = "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also iat.

Example: df.iat[iTH row, jTH column]

Comment: I'd rather use df.loc because I have 52 columns so it is easier to just use their names rather than positions. But thanks!